# Move Living Room in front

Tags: flooring

I want to move the Lounge/Living by the front lawn, how should I revamp this and where should I move the drawing room
[image: Ground Floor Plan]

Comment: Can you describe the intended uses of the lounge and the drawing rooms? Do you need 2 different rooms, or could they be combined?

Comment: This question seems very opinion based and isn't a really good fit for our format.  If you have a specific question with a factual answer, that would work better.

Answer (score 1):

Can’t you just flip the uses? Rooms seem similar in size, except the existing Lounge has a lot of circulation and the existing Drawing Room can be private.

Otherwise, a major remodel might be to switch the kitchen with the Lounge. Put the Lounge in the back with the bedrooms and add a large curved island bar (with barstools) in the center “domed” area.

In my house, everyone gathers around the bar area.

BTW, do you have a refrigerator?